React is ignoring / not executing DOM modification by JQuery or javascript
I have a
App.jsx file
function App() {

  return (
    <>
          <small>Date is<span class="date"></span></small>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

Script.js file
var s= new Date();
$("." + date).text(s);

this is working fine with HTML pages but not in react pages.I tried using inline script, using javascript .textContent, .innerHTML but nothing is working.
I don't have access to directly make changes in the react file so how could i make it work such scenarios.

My guess: React rerenders the view and overwrites your changes. There isn't much you can do, especially without [mcve].

don't use jquery with react unless you have to, they are made to avoid using the other

If not jquery is there any other way  to add year

@Bhrth have you tried using devtools to debug? if yes then what's the error?

@LãNgọcHải i'm not seeing any errors for this.

@Bhrth then it could be like the first comment suggested, the code ran but got overwritten. Without an actual [mre] we can't help you further.

@LãNgọcHải i have added the sample of similar code would that be helpful ?

@Bhrth no, it doesn't help reproducing the problem. Also, I'm pretty sure you can't use class in React, it should be className

What is "." + date supposed to be? Did you mean ".date"? In any case, the element probably doesn't exist in the document when you try and run your jQuery code
